# Performance Optimizations - Object Caches

Tags: objective-c, caching, cocos2d-iphone

So I have a game I'm working on using cocos2d. The game involves many enemy projectiles, as well as a few friendly projectiles to collide with the enemy projectiles.

Both the enemy and friendly projectiles are objects with properties such as:

- sprite (used for CCMoveTo, actions)
- hitbox (CGRect)
- travel duration
- trajectory

And it also has methods to calculate travel time, trajectory, and other things which are determined based on a random spawn location.

Currently what I'm doing is creating these objects each time a projectile is spawned, adding them to arrays (i.e. friendlyProjectiles, enemyProjectiles), iterating through these for collision detection, and releasing the object when they collide.

Would it be better to use a cache for objects here?

For example:

- at startup create 100 enemy projectile objects, 5 friendly projectile objects
- place these objects on a stack
- when a projectile is spawned, instead of creating the object, I pop from the stack
- when a projectile collides and is destroyed, instead of releasing the object, I just remove it from the layer and array, and push it back on the stack
- when a projectile is spawned I still have to calculate it's trajectory, velocity, distance, etc, but I don't have to re-create the object

Is this a good approach?

I'm relatively new to Objective C, would I run into problems where I'm trying to push and pop to the stack at the same time?

Comment: are your projectiles a subclass of CCSprite, or do you have a CCSprite? if you were a subclass you could just add them to your projectile spritesheet, and then remove them when your physics logic dictates.

Comment: Projectiles are not currently a subclass of CCSprite, but each one of them has a CCSprite as a property.

Comment: if simulator is lagging then I can say with near certainty that it will be bad on the device

Answer (score 2):

The main question that you should ask is:

**Is there a performance problem with the way that you are doing it now?**

If not, then why complicate things.

If there is a problem, then profile the app to see if this is where the problem is.
If this is it then yes, this sounds like reasonable approach.

Comment: I'm still waiting to get an actual iPad to test on, but the simulator does lag when I get a large amount of projectiles. Does the simulator attempt to emulate the processing power of an actual device, or is it dependent on my hardware?

Comment: The simulator is dependent on your hardware, and typically faster than the actual iPad.

Comment: I have an i5 3570k at 4.7 GHz, so I'd say I need to optimize my performance.

Comment: I see a few places with potential problems, so I'm going to try and improve them all. Is there a better approach than what I mentioned in the OP, or any modifications I should make?

Comment: Not as far as I can see from this, but just storing then in an `NSArray` when you aren't using them is good.  You may want to just create them as needed if the array is empty though, instead of creating a bunch of them up front.

Comment: cpu is faster, rendering a lot slower. Make no assumptions based on simulator performance, it's futile.

Comment: **Until you quantify an actual performance issue, you don't need an object cache.**  It is unlikely that object allocation is a bottleneck in this case and much more likely that it is fallout from having so much on screen at once.

Comment: The biggest problem is iterating through large arrays for collision detection. I'm just putting off fixing that, and thought I could get some performance improvement from an object cache. It would only take me an hour or two to implement.